# クローズ投票時のダイアログに、コメントを残すよう求める表示を追加しませんか？

Tags: 討議, 機能の要求, コメント, 質問のクローズ

現状、クローズ投票のほとんどにコメントがありません。

クローズ投票ダイアログに、例えば以下のようなメッセージを表示してみませんか？

> クローズ投票する際は、できるだけ質問者が質問を改善するための具体的なアドバイスをコメントとして残してください。

クローズが成立するとヘルプセンターへのリンクは張られますが、抽象的なことしか書いてないので、あれを読んで質問を改善するのもなかなか難しいと感じます。

Comment: [この質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/38356/19110)がクローズされたのを見て、この変更は必要だと思うようになりました。このご提案は、どういう状態になれば status-planned にできるのでしょう？　プラス投票は充分集まっているように感じます。

Comment: @nekketsuuu 単純に、モデレーター含むサイト運営側が忘れている、ないしフォローしきれてない可能性が高いです。通報すると、モデレーターのキューに積まれるので、対応を促すことができます。ひとまず、どうやったらこの修正を行えるのか、確認してみます。

Comment: 追記: Juan さんにどうやったら反映できるか確認中。。

Comment: (該当の文面は、英語だと全 StackExchange 共通かもしれないです。そして、翻訳を柔軟に行うことによる対応は、今の翻訳ツールの仕様上、メンテ不能になるかもと思っています)

Comment: メモ: このメタ投稿に関連して生じたチャットで、どうして「必ずコメントととして残してください」ではあまり良くないのかについて議論があり、私自身有益な議論だなと思ったのでここにログへのリンクを残しておきます。 [ログ1](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40701960#40701960), [ログ2](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40818505#40818505)

Answer (score 4):

文案です

---

クローズ投票する際はなるべく、質問を改善するための具体的なアドバイスをコメントとして残してください。

Comment: 「できるだけ」がどこにかかっているのか曖昧なので、受ける単語の直前に移動していただけると、意図がさらに明確になるものと思います。

Comment: 「できるだけ」を文末の方に移すだけだと少し違和感があるので、「クローズ投票する際はなるべく、質問を改善するための具体的なアドバイスをコメントとして残してください。」ではどうでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

I would appreciate the translation of this answer.

---

私の質問の理解が正しければ、本件はすでにシステムに存在します。

#### 既存の理由でクローズ

質問がクローズされる際には特別なバナーが表示されます。バナーには質問の何が良くないのか、そして質問が再オープンされるためには投稿者が何をするべきかが記されています。この場合、質問のクローズ理由インターフェイスに表示されるテキストテキストが何かはわかっています（変更可能です！）。しばらく前にクロージングシステムが更新され、[オーディエンスごとに異なるテキストを指定](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4710/118690)できるようになりました。つまり、クローズされた質問の投稿者、クローズに投票したユーザーや再オープン特権を持つユーザーへは別のフレーズが表示されます。

#### コメントをつけてクローズ

既存のクローズ理由の中に正しいものが見つからない場合は、「コミュニティ特有の理由」セクションに移動して、コメントをつけて質問をクローズすることができます。この場合、コメントは投票した直後に質問に表示されます。

上記を考慮すると、追加のコメントを求めることは、投稿者とクローズ投票を行ったユーザーの両サイドにとって少し過剰であると思われてしまう可能性がないとは言えません。

#### 最後に一言

クローズ理由のフレーズというものはコミュニティや文化固有のものだと思います。例えば、Stack Overflow ロシア語版でのクローズ理由のフレーズは、英語版からの直接的な翻訳は事実上存在しません。スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版のクローズ理由のフレーズを何らかの形で適応させたい場合は、[Traducir.win](https://ja.traducir.win/)の翻訳インターフェースを介して行うことができます。個人的には、やりがいがあると思います！