# 競技プログラミングの文脈で「WAがでます」と言っているだけの質問は意図がはっきりしませんか？

Tags: 討議, クローズ理由

先日「AtCoder ARC 057 B」というご質問が投稿されました。

- [AtCoder ARC 057 B](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/48331/19110)

内容としては AtCoder という競技プログラミングのサイトの特定の問題に関して、自分の方針とソースコードを載せた上で、特定のテストケースにおいて Wrong Answer (WA) になることを説明しています。

このご質問が「質問内容がはっきりしない」という理由でクローズされたのですが、これだけだとそこまで質問意図が分からないものなのでしょうか？　自分としては「こう書いたらエラーになる」とだけ書かれた質問とそう変わらないように感じました。

エラーを解決したい (つまり、AC にしたい) という部分は推測できるので、コメントで「エラー原因を知りたいのか、その原因を克服するためにはどう書けばいいのか知りたいのかどっちですか？」と聞く程度は必要かと思いますが、クローズするほどなのでしょうか？

自分は競技プログラミングの文脈を知っているので、他の方の感じ方は違うかもしれないな、と思い今回メタに投稿してみました。なぜ質問内容がはっきりしないと感じられたのかが分かれば、どのように書けば多くの人に意図が伝わりやすくなるか、別の FAQ 的投稿ができそうだなと思っています。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします <(_ _)>

※ なお、競技プログラミングに関するご質問は以前にも [AIZU ONLINE JUDGEの0009で何回やってもTime Limit Exceedと表示されます。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/45304/19110) が投稿されています。

- 関連？

  - [How to deal if the user asks for code in online programming competition?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278771/5989200) -- Stack Overflow Meta
  - [Where to ask competitive programming related problems actually?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298212/5989200) -- Stack Overflow Meta

Comment: タイトルが質問内容をもっと具体的に表せていればクローズにならなかったのかもな、と今ふと思いました。問題名だけでなくたとえば「動的計画法が特定のケースで失敗するバグを直したい -- AtCoder ARC 057 B」みたいな形の方が質問意図が分かりやすくなりそうです。

Comment: 回答するまでも無いかなぁくらいの疑問なのですが、外部リンクって回答の場合は内容を回答に落とし込むのに、質問の場合は落とし込まなくても良かったんでしたっけ？例えばこの質問の場合、協議プログラミングの問題がオフラインになってしまったら質問自体回答出来ないものになってしまうかと思います。

Comment: @Myaku さん、ありがとうございます。はい、そこは僕も悩んでいるところです。コードに関してはコピペしてほしいと思うのですが、問題文に関しては丸々コピペだと引用の範囲内にはならないんじゃないかなあと思います。そこで、自分の実装方針を書くようにすれば、問題とはある程度独立した質問にできるのではないかなあと考えているのですが、それで上手くQ&Aが永続的に回るのかよく分かりません。

Comment: 大まかにどう言った計算をしたいのかという考えと、コードは確かに質問文中に記載して欲しいですね。あくまで外部リンクは引用できないが考え方の元になった補足程度で……。あんまりオフトピにはしたくないのはありますが、リンクが切れてしまった場合には、引用の範囲を超えてしまうから質問文だけをみて回答できない質問になってしまった～、であればSOで扱えないという意味でオフトピなのかなぁと思いました。

Answer (score 8):

件の投稿に質問文が記されていないのは紛れもない事実であり、質問文が無いのであれば「質問内容がはっきりしない」のも当然の結果ではないでしょうか？

また競技プログラミングの文脈において「特定のテストケース」であり、またテストケースが明かされないことが常識だというのは理解できます。しかし、スタックオーバーフローは競技プログラミング関連サイトでなくQ&Aサイトです。Q&Aサイトにおいてこれは「内容がはっきりしないテストケース」でしかなく、「テストケースを明確にしてください」としか答えようがなく、これについても「質問内容がはっきりしない」の一因ではないでしょうか。

---

誤解されている方がおられるようなので補足を。

もちろん競技プログラミングを敵視するつもりは全くありません。純粋にQ&AサイトにおけるQとして相応しくないという意見です。

「AtCoder ARC 057 B」や「WAがでます」でなぜいけないのか、それはこれを質問として受け入れた場合にQ&Aサイトとしての回答は「ACしている方のコードを使用してください」で済んでしまいます。**他人のコード**はQ&Aサイトの**回答**としては受け入れられても、競技プログラミングの**解答**としては受け入れられないでしょう。

他人のコードを望んでいないのであれば「WAがでます」で済まさず、

- XXというテストケースは問題ないことは確認しているが、引っかかりそうなテストケースを見つけて欲しい
- コードブロックのこの辺りは自信があるが、ここは自信がないので見て欲しい

等々、なんであれ質問者が自分で書いたコードについて議論を展開した上で、自分のコードに対する見解を求める必要があると考えます。
それがなされていれば、自然と質問形の文が含まれるでしょうし、タイトルも問題番号などにはならないでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます！　1点目については、普段「エラーが出ます」とだけ書かれた質問がクローズされているのを見ないので、それに加えて何か別のネガティブな要因があるのかなあと思い、今回のメタ投稿に至りました。2点目については私が考えたことのない側面からのご指摘でハッとしました。上手くいかないテストケースの具体的な内容を提示できないという欠点を補うのに、似たような間違い方をしているらしい他のコードを出すのでは足りないでしょうか？

Comment: 今回はテストケースがあるとはっきりしているので「失敗する具体例を出してほしい」という方向になるのは理解できるのですが、それと同じ指摘を「よく分からないのだけどこのプログラムがたまに失敗する」みたいな形式の質問には出せないんじゃないかと思います。問題解決に向けて情報をより詳細にした方がクローズされやすくなってしまう逆進性に見え、違和感を覚えます。一方で、テストケースを強調しないように書いた方が不信感を持たれにくいということなのかなとも思いました。

Answer (score 6):

クローズの是非、それ以前の問題があるように思います。
端的に言うと、サイト初心者に対して [行動規範](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct) に沿わない不親切な対応になっています。

#### 質問文に関して

質問文が無いというのは事実ですし、質問者さんもこの程度の指摘にはすぐに対応すればそれで済むのに、とも思います。しかし、

> 質問文が見当たりませんが、Q&Aサイトで何を主張されたいのでしょうか？

という指摘の仕方は一般的には「嫌み」に分類されるものです。あまり良いものでは無かったと思います。

#### 用語に関して

私も「WA」や「AC」は解らなかったです。しかし、自分に解らない言葉があるからクローズする、というのはあんまりでは無いでしょうか。この点はさすがに考え直していただきたいと思います。

#### タイトルやテストケースに関する説明の不備に関して

これらの指摘も理解できます。しかし、こういったことを Meta サイトで議題になってから指摘しはじめるというのは大変によろしくないと思います。まして、このサイトを初めて利用する質問者だったのですから、改善が必要な点は全て説明するべきでした。過去の議論で再三指摘されて来たことです。

---

追記:
私はクローズ理由を説明すべきとの議論が繰り返された結果、[クローズ投票ダイアログへのコメントを残すよう求める記載を入れませんか](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2552/3054) の提案がなされたと記憶していましたが、どうも Meta サイトを検索しても出てきません。記憶違いのようですので、

> 過去の議論で再三指摘されて来た

という発言を撤回いたします。

Comment: 回答にも書きましたが、競技プログラミングに関わらずクローズは適切だったと判断しています。ところで行動規範は今回初めて見ました。普段ツアーやヘルプセンターはよく参照していますがそれでも見かけたことがありません。どこからリンクされているドキュメントなのでしょうか？ ともあれ今後は注意します。「改善が必要な点は全て説明するべき」という方針も初めて知りました。再三指摘された過去の議論を例示していただけたらと思います。

Comment: 行動規範は、ほんの最近にできたものですね。今見るとヘルプの「弊社のモデル」に入っていました。あとはサイト初心者の質問に回答を書くと解答の入力欄の上にリンクが出たりもするようです。

Comment: @sayuri  「改善が必要な点は全て説明するべき」は私の意見です。
私は「クローズ理由は解るけれどコメントで指摘してあげるべきだったのでは？」→「それはそうでした」といった議論が繰り返しあったと記憶していたのですが、記憶違いだったようです。クローズされた個々の質問のコメント欄での議論だったのかも知れませんが、いずれにしろ大勢が参加した議論は無かったようですので、「過去の議論で再三指摘」という部分を撤回いたしました。

Answer (score 3):

・タイトルは質問内容を簡潔に説明すべきで、「AtCoder ARC 057 B」というタイトルはあまりに投げやりだと思います。

・私は競技プログラミングについて詳しくないので、恐らく用語と思われる「WA」や「AC」という単語も一見しただけでは理解できませんでした。

・ソースコードが「リンク先」に貼ってありますが、普段「リンク先のコンテンツは消える可能性があるので、問題が再現する最低限のコードをSOに直接載せてください」といったやり取りがされているかと思います(しかも今回は他人のコードの"引用"ではなく、ご本人のコードですよね)。

・「○○番のテストケースが通らない」も「○番目」は他人に説明するなら不適切で、その「内容」の方が重要なのではないでしょうか。
「競技プログラミングだから詳細は伏せられている？」というのも、そのサイトの"外"の人に説明する際に通用する話なのででしょうか？

プログラミングの話を抜きにしても、(sayuriさんが指摘された通り）質問文が見当たりません。
書かれているのは「WAが出る」「プログラムの方針」「他人の結果と比べると～で間違えているかも」など起こった事実を書き並べただけで、そこから「どうしたいのか」がはっきりしません。

---

(コメントに対して追記)
「**界隈では専門用語的に広く使われている**」の界隈にSOは含まれていますか？界隈とは「ある特定の範囲＝狭い範囲」と同じ意味ではないでしょうか。
同じように界隈で使われている単語、例えば「DOS窓(コマンドプロンプト)」「火狐(Firefox)」などを使用することは説明として分かりやすい・親切でしょうか？(特に質問に限らず回答の場合でも)

念を押しておくとこれらの略語/知らない単語が例え使われていたとしても、それ**だけ**を理由にクローズに私は投票しません。

Comment: ありがとうございます！　「WA」「AC」については界隈では専門用語的に広く使われている言葉なので、そこを書き直してサイトを見るすべての人に通じるように書くべきなのか悩みました（他の質問に対してもそこまで厳しい対応をしているでしょうか？）。もちろん、「WA」を知らない方から見ると「エラーが出ている」ということすら分からないので質問意図が分かりにくかったという側面はあると思うので、これも FAQ には書いておくべきですね。

Comment: どのテストが通らないのかという話は sayuri さんの回答に書いたコメントと同じで、質問者さんにとってもテストの内容は分からないため、代わりに同様の間違いをしていると思われる回答を挙げているわけですよね。この点については「失敗しているケースの具体的な内容は分かりません」と一文書き添えれば充分でしょうか？